# Grafana: Error after updating: 'The page isn’t redirecting properly', or 'redirected you too many times.'

Tags: iis, grafana

I have Grafana running under Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS). IIS is configured with URL Rewrite as a Reverse Proxy. After upgrading Grafana from version 9 to version 10 it will no longer work from an external browser. (It works fine with the browser on the same machine as the Grafana installation, if connecting to 'localhost:3000').
Both Firefox and Chrome browser indicate that there are 'too many redirects' and suggest I clear Cache and Cookies. Which I did, but that makes no difference.
After downgrading Grafana to version 9.15 it immediately works fine again.
What could be the problem ?

Comment: Clearly the version upgrade is the problem. Review what rewrite rules you have on IIS and how the new version redirects differently, then the culprit should be clearer. Not a surprise if there are extra things around enforcing HTTPS.

Comment: You need to find out what causes too many redirects, you can try to use failed request tracking to view the complete request process.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem after upgrading from Grafana 9 to Grafana 10. But, I'm using Kubernetes ingress with a configured rewrite, and my Grafana was set to listen on the path `/grafana(/|$)(.*)` with rewrite.

To resolve the issue, I simply removed the rewrites and had Grafana listen on the path `/grafana`.

After making this change, everything started working as expected once again.

Hope this helps. ‍

Comment: I just upgrade my grafana server from 9 to 10 and stumbled upon the same issue. After applying your proposal, the "too many redirects" issue got fixed !
I am adding this heads up in order to push your fix :)
Thanks again